# Count number of cells with specifc text and specific colour in excel range where the text is derived from another column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Perhaps easier looking at the data,

[image: ExcelTable]

I basically need to know how many cells in red are under each country using a formula or VBA. I was able to get a function off the internet which counts the total number of red  background cells but this does not do the job. I need the number of red cells by country. My output should look like this,

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Are the colors changed manually or by some logic with conditional formatting

Comment: Post the formula you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formula solution without helper column, please see

1] Assume "Source table" put in `A1:B26` include "Status" column filled with `red` and `green` background color

2] "Output table" put in `A29:B34` include criteria country put in range `A30:A34` (Argentina, China, Australia....)

3] In "Output" header criteria `B29`, of wording "`RED`" must filled with `red` background color

4] "Output" select `B30` >> Define Name >>

'>> Name : `CountColor`

'>> Refer to :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$26=$A30)*(GET.CELL(63,IF(1,+OFFSET($B$2:$B$26,ROW($B$2:$B$26)-ROW($B$2),)))=GET.CELL(63,$B$29)))
```

Then,

5] In "Output" `B30`, enter formula and copied down :

```
=CountColor
```

6] Finally save file in `xlsm` type

Edit : Get.Cell is a Excel 4 Macro function, you need to save the file as Macro-Enable Workbook xlsm type.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$26=$A30)*(GET.CELL(63,IF(1,+OFFSET($B$2:$B$26,ROW($B$2:$B$26)-ROW($B$2),)))=GET.CELL(63,$B$29)))

Upon using this I get an error 'The function is not valid.' I'm probably doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Few points : 1] criteria country put in range A30:A34 (Argentina, China, Australia....)  2] Criteria cell B29 of wording "RED" must filled with red color. 3] Select B30 then click "Define name" and enter the formula as above description. Finally save file as xlsm type.